# Push different data to array depending the value of a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have a page with some sliders that produce some css code:(It is a box shadow generator)
I have a button that adds the produced code to a specific area(#saved ul) and passes that code to an array called used(I use this array to check if the user has added again a code to that area.If the code exists in the array a message will appear " The combination has been used").But today i came up to a problem.As you know box shadow has 2 ways to be applied:

1. outset
2. inset

To change the way the box shadow is applied I use a slider.If the value of the slider is 0 it will be outset else it will be inset.

Now back to my problem.When the user chooses to add a code that has used again the page throws a message(The combination has been used).But if the user changes the slider to select inset box shadow which is different brom outset the message will appear again.
Here is my code:

```
$("#mark").click(function(){
        var marking=$("#x").val()+$("#y").val()+$("#blur").val()+$("#spread").val();
        if (marking==0){
            console.log("No code changed");
        }
        else{

        var x=$("#x").val()+"px ";
            var y=$("#y").val()+"px ";
            var b=$("#blur").val()+"px ";
            var s=$("#spread").val()+"px ";
            $r=$("#red").val();
            $g=$("#green").val();
            $b=$("#blue").val();
            $color=" rgb("+$r+","+$g+","+$b+")";
            var finalCode=0;
            if($("#blur").val()==0 && $("#spread").val()==0){
                finalCode=x+y;
            }
            else if($("#blur").val() != 0 && $("#spread").val()==0) {
                finalCode=x+y+b;
            }
        if ($("#inset").val()==0) {
            if (used.indexOf((finalCode+$color)) != -1){
                alert("That combination has been used");
            }
            else{
            $("#saved ul").append("<li class='text-warning h3 marked'>box-shadow:"+finalCode+$color+";</li>");
            used.push(finalCode+$color);
        }

        }
        else{
            if (used.indexOf((finalCode+$color)) != -1){
                alert("That combination has been used");
            }
            else{
            $("#saved ul").append("<li class='text-success h3 marked'> box-shadow:inset "+finalCode+$color+";</li>");

        }
        }
}

    });
```

Any ideas???

Comment: What did you get with your current approach ?

Comment: How about binding if it's inset or outset with http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/ to the li element and then just check if it's in used and the element has the same in/outset value as the slider has currently?

Comment: @wawa Can you give me an example?

Comment: @stranger4js just thought about it, since you use an native array and not a jQuery DOM node, there's not much you can do with jQuery.data. What I'd do is to use two arrays instead of one. Instead of the `used` array I'd use an `usedInset` and `usetOutset` array and just perform the checks on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but it should work like this.

```
var used = {
    inset   : [],
    outset  : []
}

$("#mark").click(function(){
    var marking=$("#x").val()+$("#y").val()+$("#blur").val()+$("#spread").val();
    if (marking==0) {
        // make sure to remove this before publishing the app
        console.log("No code changed");
    } else{
        var x=$("#x").val()+"px ";
        var y=$("#y").val()+"px ";
        var b=$("#blur").val()+"px ";
        var s=$("#spread").val()+"px ";
        $r=$("#red").val();
        $g=$("#green").val();
        $b=$("#blue").val();
        $color=" rgb("+$r+","+$g+","+$b+")";
        var finalCode=0;
        if($("#blur").val()==0 && $("#spread").val()==0){
            finalCode=x+y;
        } else if ($("#blur").val() != 0 && $("#spread").val()==0) {
            finalCode=x+y+b;
        }
        if ($("#inset").val()==0) {
            if (used.inset.indexOf((finalCode+$color)) != -1){
                alert("That combination has been used");
            } else{
                $("#saved ul").append("<li class='text-warning h3 marked'>box-shadow:"+finalCode+$color+";</li>");
                used.inset.push(finalCode+$color);
            }
        } else {
            if (used.outset.indexOf((finalCode+$color)) != -1){
                alert("That combination has been used");
            } else{
                $("#saved ul").append("<li class='text-success h3 marked'> box-shadow:inset "+finalCode+$color+";</li>");
                used.outset.push(finalCode+$color);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you prefer you could use to vars for inset and outset

```
var usedInset = [];
var usedOutset = new Array();
// what ever you prefere
[...]
if ($("#inset").val()==0) {
    if (usedInset.indexOf((finalCode+$color)) != -1){
        alert("That combination has been used");
    } else{
        $("#saved ul").append("<li class='text-warning h3 marked'>box-shadow:"+finalCode+$color+";</li>");
        usedInset.push(finalCode+$color);
    }
} else {
    if (usedOutset.indexOf((finalCode+$color)) != -1){
        alert("That combination has been used");
    } else{
        $("#saved ul").append("<li class='text-success h3 marked'> box-shadow:inset "+finalCode+$color+";</li>");
        usedOutset.push(finalCode+$color);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps (: